# SAS macro function to get file modified date on linux

Tags: linux, sas, sas-macro

Working on a macro function to return the modified date of a file as a SAS date, that will run on Linux (SAS 9.3).  I want to avoid using OS commands (e.g. piping the results of an LS command) as code needs to work in an environment with NOXCMD.  Below is a first draft (no error handling code, etc), using finfo().

Was disappointed by the format of the date returned by finfo(), e.g."Fri Apr 10 14:54:10 2015". Then was more disappointed by my inability to input() this string without the ugly parsing below. I have generally avoided using ANYDTDTE informat in the past, out of fear that it does too much guessing and doesn't throw errors.  But it feels like overkill to write a custom date-time informat to handle this string.

Would appreciate thoughts on better ways to convert the date string to a SAS date, better ways to get the file modified date, and any pitfalls to below.

```
%macro GetModDate(file);
  %*Get the modified date of a linux file, as SAS date;
  %local rc fref fid ModDate;

  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(fref,&file));
  %let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&fref));

  %let ModDate=%sysfunc(finfo(&fid,Last Modified));

  %*Linux Last Modified returns format like: Fri Apr 10 14:54:10 2015;
  %let ModDate=%sysfunc(inputn(%scan(&moddate,2,%str( )) %scan(&moddate,3,%str( )) %scan(&moddate,5,%str( ))
                              ,anydtdte11
                               ));
  %let fid=%sysfunc(fclose(&fid));
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(fref));

  &ModDate
%mend GetModDate;
```

Comment: While I think this is fine here - technically speaking if this is "finished code" that you want help improving it belongs on [codereview.se].  I don't actually post over there and I don't know if any SAS users do - so I tend to be fine with them here - just noting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Joe.  As I wrote it, I was thinking this might be off-topic for SO, since I couldn't figure out how to make it into a question that would have a *correct* answer.  Will keep this in mind for future posts.

Comment: just couldn't understand what was in that discussion. a question? an answer? asking for suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't happen on Windows, at least.  I get a nice SAS datetime.

Adding some debugging:

```
%macro GetModDate(file);
  %*Get the modified date of a linux file, as SAS date;
  %local rc fref fid ModDate;

  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(fref,&file));
  %put &=rc;
  %let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&fref));
  %put &=fid;
  %let ModDate=%sysfunc(finfo(&fid,Last Modified));
  %put &=ModDate;
  %*Linux Last Modified returns format like: Fri Apr 10 14:54:10 2015;
  %let ModDate=%sysfunc(inputn(%scan(&moddate,2,%str( )) %scan(&moddate,3,%str( )) %scan(&moddate,5,%str( ))
                              ,anydtdte11
                               ));
  %let fid=%sysfunc(fclose(&fid));
  %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(fref));

  &ModDate
%mend GetModDate;

%getModDate(c:\temp\test.html)
```

returns

```
RC=0
FID=2
MODDATE=19Mar2015:10:19:09
```

I'm not sure there's a better way if Linux does work the way you want, though, though you could make some improvement to avoid ANYDTDTE if you're already going to the effort of parsing it out some by hand.

For example:

```
%let ModDate=
    %sysfunc(inputn(
        %scan(&moddate,3,%str( ))%scan(&moddate,2,%str( ))%scan(&moddate,5,%str( )),
        date9.)
     );
```

Comment: Yes, it's one of only a few times that I've been disappointed to run SAS code on Linux rather than Win.  I was shocked when I saw what Linux returned.  Appreciate your suggestion to replace ANYDTDTE with DATE9, that will feel a bit safer.

Comment: Note of course that I swap the 3 and the 2 to make it match DATE9.

Comment: Also: I would suggest opening a track with Tech Support.  If for no other reason than to get them to update [this page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/67464/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0rtd85lrdft6en1mhzqfbp55fv4.htm) which still lists only the pre-9.2 options.  That datetime format is total nonsense to me, though - SAS clearly parses the datetime on Windows (as that's nothignglike the windows format) so it should be able to figure it out for you as well.

Comment: Good point, will open the track.  Indeed, I had read that page a couple months ago and thought "I can't believe Linux SAS can't tell me the modified date!" and then only today came back to it and realized the docs are wrong.

Comment: I have to say I don't entirely understand the format ext4 uses for its timestamps.  The only thing I can imagine is this format is compatible with some older formats that omit the year, but that's just weird.

Comment: I contacted Tech Support.  They said SAS 9.4 on Linux returns a nice datetime same as windows.   Messy log in-line here, but key point is it returns e.g. 15Oct2014:11:30:00  %put Host OS: &sysscp &sysscpl ;

Host OS: LIN X64 Linux

3    %put SAS Version: &sysvlong ;

SAS Version: 9.04.01M2P072314

4

5    %let file=test.txt ;

6    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(fref,&file));

7    %let fid=%sysfunc(fopen(&fref));

8

9    %let ModDate=%sysfunc(finfo(&fid,Last Modified));

10   %put ModDate: &ModDate ;

ModDate: 15Oct2014:11:30:00